# Cross-platform app for all notifications

Tags: cross-platform, notification, social-networks

Since it's hard and annoying and addictive to always have open tabs of all my social media networks, I was thinking if I could have one app that would have it all. I'd like that app to be for Windows, Linux, BSD, Android, J2ME and/or web for those platforms that don't have it.

The networks would need to be:

- IP Boards boards
- phpBB boards
- Facebook
- deviantART
- Google+
- YouTube
- Hotmail
- AVRFreaks
- SMF
- Weasyl
- Stack Exchange

Does anyone know if such exists?